# Move dial numbers on gauge highchart?

Tags: highcharts, numbers, move, gauge

I have a gauge style high chart I am working on, and I cannot for the life of me figure out how to move the numbers on the dial inwards towards the center of the gauge. These are the numbers on the scale. How do I do this?

Comment: You mean number under needle or numebrs on scale?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `offset` parameter http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#yAxis.offset with i.e negative value.

http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#yAxis.offset